# How do I estimate time specific unobservable variables with panel data?

Tags: panel-data, stata, instrumental-variables, time-varying-covariate, generalized-moments

I have a problem that deals with human capital. I assume that wages $W_{it}$ are determined by the level of human capital $K_{it}$ and the market clearing rental rate that applies to all workers $R_{t}$,
\begin{equation}
W_{it}=R_{t}K_{it}
\end{equation}
The key part of the problem is that neither the rental rate or human capital are observed, but with proper functional forms it is possible to derive some implications.
Borrowing from a paper by Shaw (1989), "Life-Cycle Labor Supply and Human Capital", I write the human capital accumulation function as a function of lagged wages and hours,
\begin{align}
K_{it+1}&=\alpha_{1}K_{it}+\alpha_{2}K_{it}^{2}+\alpha_{3}h_{it}+\alpha_{4}h_{it}^{2}+\alpha_{5}K_{it}h_{it}+\epsilon_{it}+v_{t}\\
\implies \frac{W_{it+1}}{R_{t+1}}&=\alpha_{1}\frac{W_{it}}{R_{t}}+\alpha_{2}(\frac{W_{it}}{R_{t}})^{2}+\alpha_{3}h_{it}+\alpha_{4}h_{it}^{2}+\alpha_{5}\frac{W_{it}}{R_{t}}h_{it}+\epsilon_{it}+v_{t}\\
\implies W_{it+1}&=\alpha_{1}\frac{W_{it}}{R_{t}}R_{t+1}+\alpha_{2}(\frac{W_{it}}{R_{t}})^{2}R_{t+1}+\alpha_{3}h_{it}R_{t+1}+\alpha_{4}h_{it}^{2}R_{t+1}+\alpha_{5}\frac{W_{it}}{R_{t}}h_{it}R_{t+1}+\epsilon_{it}+v_{t}
\end{align}
This last equation I am trying to estimate using GMM. The difficult part is estimating the unobservable rental rate in each year. I thought of using time dummies as an IV (such that D=1 if year=1980 and D=0 if year != 1980) and estimating the the equation for the number of years I have available and each year the dummy variable changes to the target year. Then the coefficients will reflect the time specific shock related to each variable (ie the change in rental rate).

**Using this method can I properly interpret the change in the say the coefficient of $h_{it}$ as equivalent to $\alpha_{4}R_{t+1}$ for that given year?**

Then assuming $\alpha_{4}$ constant dividing the coefficient in the current period by the previous period yields $\frac{R_{t+1}}{R_{t}}$. Normalizing $R_{1}=1$ the rental rates can be calculated. But my results aren't quite the same as Shaw's.

my stata code looks like,

[image]